# windows 8 store app limit orientation of selected views or grids

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

is there any way to restrict selected views orientation properties in windows 8 C# xaml programing.

Answer (score 1):

You can set preferred orientation by this.

```csharp
DisplayProperties.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Landscape | DisplayOrientations.LandscapeFlipped;
```

Please note, this is applicable to whole app, so you have to keep changing the values when necessary.

**If you test this in simulator it won't work, you need to test it in real device.**

Comment: is there any better way to keep the attribute to the views other than to change the property of entire app?

Comment: No, it may not be available. You can use rotate transform to keep the orientation of individual controls.